# UWP: How do I get size of images used in the carousel control in my View model?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using a carousel control which displays different images, I want to be able to get size of the images used in the carousel in my view model for some calculations. How do I do this ?

MainPage.xaml

```
 <Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d">

 <Grid>
<Border Margin="0">
  <controls:Carousel x:Name="CarouselControl"
              InvertPositive="True"
              ItemDepth="300"
              ItemMargin="340"
              ItemRotationX="0"
              ItemRotationY="45"
              ItemRotationZ ="0"
              Orientation="Horizontal"
              SelectedIndex="4">
    <controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
      <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
    </controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
    <controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Image 
              x:Name ="Images"
              Width="200"
              Height="200"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
              Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"
              Stretch="Uniform" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
  </controls:Carousel>
</Border>
```

How do I access size of images in x:Name =" Images" in the View model for this xaml page?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I access size of images in x:Name =" Images" in the View model for this xaml page?

So you want to get all the size value of all the images that you used, right?

What's the Thumbnail that you used to bind, is it a Uri that points to the image? If it is a Uri, to get the size of the local file, you could create a [StorageFile object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile?view=winrt-19041) using the Uri and then get the Width and Height using a [BitmapDecoder class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder?view=winrt-19041).

Here is a code sample that you could refer to:

```
   StorageFile sf =  await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri($"ms-appx:///Assets/london.png"));
        BitmapDecoder dec = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(await sf.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
        var width = dec.PixelWidth;
        var height = dec.PixelHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the `ItemsSource` of the `Carousel` to a collection property of the view model that returns items that represents the images to be displayed in the view.

You could then bind the `Width` and `Height` properties of the `Image` element in the view to corresponding source properties of this object, just like you currently seem to bind the the `Source` target property to a `Thumbnail` source property.

So move the `Thumbnail` property to a new class that represents an image or an item and then add `Width` and `Height` properties to the same class and bind to them in the XAML markup.